# if I plan to change the sort order of my attributes, do I need to use flexible or rigid attribute relationship type

Tags: ssas-2008-r2

I want on occasion to add new members to an existing dimension.

Sometimes the new member will be inserted into the existing sort order by increasing by 1 the integer sort values of the member currently occupying that sort position and those that follow after it.

The preexisting members will still have the same parent and child members.

My question is, since only the sort position and not the family relationships (sibling, parent, child) change between the members, can I use the rigid relationship type? If not, why?

Thank you in advance for your reply.